# Strange rendering behaviour with parenthesis in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am rendering a Text with a custom string inside it surrounded by parenthesis. I am not sure if this is a bug or I am doing something wrong, as the alignment seems totally broken.

Here is the code:

```
Text("All ()()\(allAutoFX.count) ))(()")
```

and here is the result, where you can see different base lines for the parenthesis before / after the count:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGVYF.jpg

Comment: i cant see any issue is iOS 14.2, xcode 12.2

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you provide a more precise description of your test case? In my tests, all the parentheses descend below the baseline by the same amount.